# How do i read another file inside the app script project?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I have this email_template.html file in my project and I don't know how to access it. I want to read the content as a string so that I can parse it.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can get html as string like this:

```
const template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("email_template");
const htmlOutput = template.evaluate();
const contentString = htmlOutput.getContent();
Logger.log(contentString);
```

Then you can parse contentString.